# PHPExcel created file cannot be downloaded with Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm currently using a `php` library that will generate a excel 2007 file.

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
$this->output->set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . 'test' . '.xlsx"');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$this->output->set_output($objWriter->save('php://output'));
```

The problem is the contents of the file that should be downloaded is echoed on the browser page. I have no problem when I coded this on a normal PHP code, but on Code Igniter I can't make the file be downloaded by the client.

I already tried using `force_download` function from the download helper of code igniter.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180017/error-phpexcel-in-codeigniter

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much. Didn't see that question. It seems that replacing all the `$this->output->set_header()` with simply a `header()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below coding.

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
$this->output->set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . 'test' . '.xlsx"');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```