# CodeIgniter Error : Fatal error: Call to private IOFactory::__construct() from context 'CI_Loader'

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was trying to implement PHPExcel through codeigniter and I am getting this error

```
 class Users extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */


public function _construct()
{
}



public function index()
{



    $this->load->library('phpexcel');
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel/iofactory');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("title")
                     ->setDescription("description");


    // Assign cell values
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'cell value here');

    // Save it as an excel 2003 file
    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    $objWriter->save("nameoffile.xls");
}
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to private IOFactory::__construct() from context 'CI_Loader' in F:\xampp\htdocs\import\system\core\Loader.php on line 1099
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180017/error-phpexcel-in-codeigniter.. Also change `_construct()` to `__construct()`. I hope that it is a typo :)

Comment: Regarding your deleted question just now, please do not delete questions when they are brand new. Comments will still be being made on them, and people will feel their time has been wasted if their comment results in a 'post deleted' error.

Comment: ok will take about this.

Answer (score 0):

class Users extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct()
{
    **parent::__construct();**
}
function index()
{
   $this->load->library('phpexcel');
   $this->load->library('PHPExcel/iofactory');

   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("title")
                 ->setDescription("description");


   // Assign cell values
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'cell value here');

   // Save it as an excel 2003 file
   $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

   $objWriter->save("nameoffile.xls");
}
```

}

[enter link description here](http://www.iartcode.com)